# Equivalence relations are to Groups, as partial order relations are to...?

Tags: category-theory

I'm a beginning student of category theory so the question is a little hazy. Apologies if it is too basic.

An equivalence relation induces a "symmetric category" (bad terminology?), where you can back from any arrow. The category induced by a group has a different symmetry. How are these two specifically related? Is an equivalence relation somehow an algebra, like a group, that specializes the category axioms? Is it more deeply analogous to a group in some way?

I know that a category can also be induced by a partial order - which encodes anti-symmetry rather than symmetry . Is there a corresponding algebra encoding antisymetry (like a group but encoding anti-symmetry instead)? I know a partial order itself has the algebra of a lattice.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This question may be better suited to the [Computer Science StackExchange site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), which is geared more towards theory. StackOverflow is geared more towards programming/engineering/implementation details.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not on-topic per [ask] & [help]. PS Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean. Vague phrases like "specifically related" are not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS You are basically asking for yet another presentation of the topic. Ask about how you are stuck in one & reference it.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set with an equivalence relation is often called a [setoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setoid). Categorically, a setoid is a [thin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posetal_category) [groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid). A groupoid may be thought of as a "multi-object group" in the same way that a category is a "multi-object monoid": that is, the endomorphisms of every object in a groupoid form a group.

A partial order is a thin [skeletal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory)) category (a preorder is simply a thin category). Therefore, the algebraic structure corresponding to a partial order (or preorder), in the same way that groups correspond to equivalence relations, is a monoid.

The relationship "an X is just a one-object Y" is called [horizontal categorification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal+categorification), where for your examples we have:

- X = group, Y = groupoid.
- X = monoid, Y = category.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot.